# Cannot Checkin SPFile Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom library in sharepoint, and my code is to allow user to upload & checkin a document.

The problem is when the file is checked-in an Access Denied exception is thrown. The user seems to have all required permissions (e.g. EditListItems, OverrideCheckOut, etc.)

Has anyone had this issue?

I saw this post here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d14cbb38-8122-4dad-a7f6-b3a75800dfba/checkoutcheckin-when-uploading-a-file?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

But i dont want to use RunWithElevatedPrivileges, anyone has any better solution?

Comment: The `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` is only being used to execute that specific piece of code, and isn't granting the user elevated privileges. So it doesn't appear (to me) be much of a security concern. It's a bit like executing a Stored Proc under the guise of another user so that for the rest of the time the user has lower privileges, which isn't uncommon.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the same user uploads file and tries to check it in? There should be way to check who checked it out...

Comment: yes same user uploads and tries to check in.

Comment: btw the user has Contribute permission, but without Delete permissions